# Template argument deduction, unclear case

Tags: c++, templates

```
class Copier{ };

template<class T>
class Destructor{ };

template<template<class T> class Abstractor>
class BuildFactory : public Abstractor<Copier>{ };

BuildFactory<Destructor> bd;
```

I can't understand what the template parameter `T` is going to be deduced to. I suspect `T` will be deduced to `Copier` but it just how I think, I can't explain that. Maybe someone can give an explantion of that topic.

Comment: @RSahu No, it's not...

Comment: @RSahu Why do you think so? I just made an assumption about it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So what's the right way?

Comment: @stella: Do you not see juanchopanza's answer, below?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, I can. But I have another doubt about it. Maybe you can look at it?

Comment: It seems nobody has mentioned yet that template argument deduction only works for template *functions*.

Comment: @ChristianHackl WHAT??? Really???? Why do you think so?

Comment: @stella: That's the definition of "template argument deduction". It means to deduce a type from an argument (the one passed to the function). You have an argument, so the type is known, and as the type is known, you don't have to specify it again. That's template argument deduction.

Comment: @stella: Because, it just is. C++11 14.8.2

Comment: Or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction, which explains the standard in a simpler language.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: That's not right. The "argument" in the name refers to "template argument". The "template argument" is deduced. The conclusion is right of course: it is not possible to deduce the arguments of a class template from its ctor.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The word "argument" is ambigous here, isn't it? It can refer to the template argument or the function argument. Is `3` not an argument if I have `template<class T> void f(T t);` and call it with `f(3)`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: In the phrase "template argument", the word "argument" refers to the template argument.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The thing being deduced is the template argument, of course. And it is deduced *from* the function argument. That's all I wanted to say. I certainly did not want to give the wrong impression that a function argument is deduced; at the same time I don't understand how this could be deduced (sorry for the pun :)) from my comments. I certainly did not intend to confuse the OP. I'll try to stress the fact that we are talking about the template argument and not the function argument when I explain this to someone in the future.

Comment: (In fact, I originally meant to write "the one passed to the function, not the template argument", then shortened it to make the comment more concise.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no deduction. Let's look at the two places where `T` exists:

```
template<template<class T> class Abstractor>
class BuildFactory : public Abstractor<Copier>{ };
```

This says that `BuildFactory` is a class template that itself takes a class template, calling it `Abstractor`. Again, to be clear: `Abstractor` is a class *template*, not an instantiation. So no deduction happens at all. The class `Abstractor<Copier>` has an explicit argument as you're naming `Copier`.

The `T` is actually not necessary; you could write:

```
template<template<class> class Abstractor>
class BuildFactory : public Abstractor<Copier>{ };
```

Now for the other code:

```
template<class T>
class Destructor{ };

BuildFactory<Destructor> bd;
```

Again, you're passing the template `Destructor`, not some class `Destructor<T>`. No deduction needed.

Besides, it's impossible to deduce template arguments for class templates, anyway. :P

Comment: Yes, now that's clear. Thatnk you so much, I understand.

Comment: No, `Abstractor<Copier>` is not explicitly instantiated.  It's implicitly instantiated at its first point of use.  Do not confuse explicit specification of the template parameter with explicit instantiation.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's an interesting point. In fact, a good way to illustrate this is to remove `bd` and add `char x[0];` to `Destructor`. It will compile fine, despite of `Abstractor<Copier>` explicitly written out in the code.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Well then it isn't instantiated at all, implicitly or not.  Better is to give `Destructor` some out-of-line member function definitions, in a separate compilation unit.  Explicit instantiation of `Destructor<Copier>` would then fail.  Implicit instantiation would compile successfully but incompletely, requiring that if those member functions actually got called, they would need to be instantiated again in the compilation unit where they exist, or suffer linker failure.

Comment: @BenVoigt Does appearing in the base class specification cause implicit template intatntiatiation?

Comment: @stella: Yes, certainly.  Section 14.7.1 begins "Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3),
the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-deﬁned object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program."  A base class is required to be a completely-defined type.

Answer (score 6):

`T` doesn't get deduced to anything. It is not even necessary. This code would be equivalent:

```
template<template<class> class Abstractor>
class BuildFactory : public Abstractor<Copier>{ };
```

It just means that `Abstractor` is a class template, and what is known as a *template template parameter*.

Usually the optional template "parameter" is used to document something about the class templates that should be used.

Comment: Yeah the key is that a template is being passed in, not a class.

Comment: Well, at the `BuildFactory<Destructor> bd;` BuildFactory template is being implicit instantiated, that caused the Destructor template to be implicit instantiated too. How can the template ever be implicit instatiated without deducing its template parameter to something?

Comment: @stella: _"that caused the Destructor template to be implicit instantiated too"_ Not true.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe, but it doesn't matter in that case. What would you say about [this](http://pastebin.com/XifMLyBA) case?

Comment: @stella I may be going blind but it looks exactly the same to me.

Comment: @stella: Same story. There's something you're fundamentally misunderstanding, and we can't tell what that is if you just keep asking the same question!

Comment: @stella: `Abstractor<Copier>` was **explicitly** named during implicit instantiation of `BuildFactory<Destructor>`, resulting in implicit instantiation of `Destructor<Copier>`.  No deduction required, because the template argument was **explicitly** provided.  And there's no instantiation of `Destructor<?>` (the template) because templates themselves are elaborated, only instances thereof.

Answer (score 2):

As previous answers have said, there's no deduction here.  In particular,

- `Abstractor` is explicitly specified as `Destructor`.
- In `BuildFactory`, `Abstractor` is explicitly used with a template parameter of `Copier`.
- In `BuildFactory<Destructor>`, since `Abstractor` is `Destructor`, that explicitly uses `Destructor<T = Copier>`.

Because all template arguments are specified, there's no deduction and not even any use of default parameter types.

Comment: Well, but what if we remove the base class specification?  `Abstractor ` will still be  `Destructor `

Comment: @stella: Using `Destructor<T=Copier>` doesn't preclude **also** using `Destructor<T2>`.  In your new example, `A` is explicitly used with an argument of `C`, and `A` is also explicitly used with an argument of `E`.  `B<D>` makes `A = D`, explicitly, so you are using `D<C>` and `D<E>`, but all the parameters are still explicitly provided, there is no deduction and no defaulting.